# Different schemas models associations Sequelize.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two MYSQL Schemas and  they must work together.

IE: The "user" table lives in the schema "a" and the "profile" table  lives in the  schema "b".

- Profile -> has many users
- Users -> belongs to Profile

Is posible to define associations between both models which lives in different schemas by this way in Sequelize js?

```
// after define the models ..

Profile.hasMany(User);
User.belongsTo(Profile);

// get the profile of the user(from the b schema)
User.find(1).success( function(user) {
    console.log(user.getProfile());
});
```

This will work?

How i should define the models from different schemas?

Comment: Any update about that?

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078970/sequelize-using-multiple-databases