# How to query multiple databases using sequelize(orm) in node.js

Tags: node.js, orm, connection, sequelize.js, mariadb

I use the Express node.js. With sequelize(mariadb).

```
show databases;
Database
> user
> board
```

I would like to use to create two database connections from a single website.

Directory Structure

```
models
|- user
    |- user.js    
|- board
    |- board.js
    |- comment.js
```

config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "test1234",
    "database": "testDB",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 3306,
    "dialect": "mariadb",
    "define": {
      "charset": "utf8",
      "collate": "utf8_general_ci"
    },
    "pool": {
      "max": 5,
      "min": 0,
      "idle": 10000
    }
  }
}
```

In the directory structure above, I need how to set sequelize connection.

One database connection has implemented a reporting api.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/

I have a lot of beginners. This little detail is required. ( ex. directory structure, config.json, index.js and so on )

Sorry, Do not speak English well.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequelize: Using Multiple Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078970/sequelize-using-multiple-databases)

Comment: Thanks. I've done it.