# mongoengine: get data and store in another DB

Tags: python, mongoengine

it is my first time to use mongoengine, I know the ORM concept. 
I want to know may I get the data in one DB and using the same object to store in another DB??

```
class User(Document):
    email = EmailField(required=True, unique= True)
    salary = IntField(require=True)

connect(alias='default',db='tumblelog')
connect(alias='testdb',db='testdb')


users = User.objects

with switch_db(User,'testdb') as User:
    for user in users:
        User(email=user.email,salary=user.email).save  # it works
        user.save() #doesn't works
```

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Have you tried doing? Facing any issue?

Comment: I tried, but I fail to stored in another DB by same object

Comment: Can you show more of your code? And what exactly is the error?

Comment: sample code in my post, and there is no error~~~just nothing happened

Answer (score -1):

I've found out that by using ORM to get a data from one DB, it will create an object unique to the DB you get it from. You won't be able to use the same object to store it into another DB.

What I would suggest is that you initialise an empty object, for example `User`, for the other DB and fill it with values from the original object and then store it.

You might want to have a look at this question. [Sequelize: Using Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078970/sequelize-using-multiple-databases)

Comment: thanks for your reply. In ORM , object is attaching to specific DB. Is it possible to do detach and attach to another DB ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Each instance of the object is created with the db info such as (db host, url, etc).