# How to connect mysql data base with sequlize with multiple data base In nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using NOdejs and my SQL for my application and it is a Sass product, 
 i need to connect  with multiple db using db name come from routes/request.

Comment: Does this answer your question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078970/sequelize-using-multiple-databases

Comment: @sandeep patel,
 Thanks for ur reply,  not solved my issues with shared soltn.
When node server is up same time sm initialising sequlize and linking my model through controllers,

I will get new db name from route based on domain name.