# Sequelize: Connect multiple databases with the same schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

Dears.

My business logic is very complicated to explain, but in general I can describe it like this: I have a central database, where I save global configuration, and have approx. 22 databases delivered around my country with the same schema. Following the Sequelize documentation, I created a configuration like this at app.js:

```
global.dbCentral = new Sequelize('mysql://dir:password@localhost:port/dbCentral', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  operatorsAliases: false
  , timezone: '-03:00' //for writing to database
});
global.dbSala = new Sequelize('mysql://dir:password@localhost:port/defaultDb', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },
  operatorsAliases: false
  , timezone: '-03:00' //for writing to database
});
```

With the central connections, I have no problem. i.e. I have created a model like this:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const Promocion = dbCentral.define('promocion', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    titulo: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    descripcion: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    monto: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        allowNull: true
    },
    img: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
        allowNull: true
    },
    activa: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: true
    },
    fecha_inicio: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    },
    fecha_fin: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true
    }
}, {
        tableName: 'promocion',
        timestamps: false
    });


Promocion.hasMany(PromocionUsuarioCruciclub, { as: 'promocion_usuario_cruciclub', foreignKey: 'id', targetKey: 'id_promocion' });

module.exports = Promocion;
```

But I don't know how to set the models that use the changing connections. If I create a dbSala for each sala I have (dbSala1,dbSala2... etc) I need to repeat each model file and it's is impossible to manage.

I thought that the answer was here: [Sequelize: Using Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078970/sequelize-using-multiple-databases) but it didn't work on my case.

I am using sequelize 4.43.0

Please, tell me if you need to explain something better

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/unetiq/using-multiple-databases-with-nodejs-and-sequelize-59e0abcbbe6f

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks you!

Comment: @AdeelNawaz, it doesn't work because it's the same thing I said up. He create a model for each database, so I have to create 22+ equeals models and I'm trying to don't do that.

Using "connectionManager.config" I can change my db source "On run time" but the problem is that if someone else is using that connection I'll kick him out

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't. Finally we take other approach to the solution, but complete different from this one

Comment: I am thinking to use sequelize in a saas application that has some data in the tenant-specific databases. I was afraid that the connection switching might be a problem, I am using Lambda functions. But any suggestions based on your 22+ db switching experience? Did you use sequelize or raw queries?

Answer (score 2):

I had success using transactions. I had a main database, for which I created the models. Then, to use the same models, but with other databases with identical structure, I simple created a transaction based on a different Sequelize instance connected to another database and passed that transaction to the models methods as part of the options parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should register all model definitions in each created sequelize instance (i.e. for each connection). Define your models as functions that have sequelize instance as a parameter and return registered model definition. 
Something like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const action = sequelize.define('action', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
// <here some other fields>
  },
    {
      schema: 'public',
      tableName: 'action'
    })

  action.associate = (models) => {
    action.belongsTo(models.resource, { foreignKey: 'resourceId' })
  }

  return action
}
```

And then use these functions to register  models in each sequelize instance.

Comment: Great! i'll try it and tell you if it works. Thanks!

Comment: so... you say if I have 22 squelize instances (Because I've got 22 db where connect) I have to create 22 models of "user", for example?

Comment: Do you connect to these 22 DBs simultaneously? If so, yes you should register all model definitions in all 22 sequelize connections.

Comment: yes, I do. Ok, I will try the way you explain and tell you the results. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

*finally using transaction solved . same model it is working , need to create anothe db details only*

```
  const rowsbackup = await ModelName.findAll({
                where: condition,
                raw: true,
                               });

                 const backup = rowsbackup.map(Data => ({ ...Data }));
                transaction = await anotherDBDetails.transaction();
                const createdBackup = await ModelName.bulkCreate(backup, { transaction });
                await transaction.commit();
```